# nvm not getting latest versions

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am not able to install v10 node using nvm

```
sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~/development/lakefrontcargo-v2-cloud-functions$ nvm install 10.15.1
Version '10.15.1' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~/development/lakefrontcargo-v2-cloud-functions$ nvm ls-remote
          <html
    iojs-v1.0.0
    iojs-v1.0.1
    iojs-v1.0.2
    iojs-v1.0.3
    iojs-v1.0.4
    iojs-v1.1.0
    iojs-v1.2.0
    iojs-v1.3.0
    iojs-v1.4.1
    iojs-v1.4.2
    iojs-v1.4.3
    iojs-v1.5.0
    iojs-v1.5.1
    iojs-v1.6.0
    iojs-v1.6.1
    iojs-v1.6.2
    iojs-v1.6.3
    iojs-v1.6.4
    iojs-v1.7.1
    iojs-v1.8.1
    iojs-v1.8.2
    iojs-v1.8.3
    iojs-v1.8.4
    iojs-v2.0.0
    iojs-v2.0.1
    iojs-v2.0.2
    iojs-v2.1.0
    iojs-v2.2.0
    iojs-v2.2.1
    iojs-v2.3.0
    iojs-v2.3.1
    iojs-v2.3.2
    iojs-v2.3.3
    iojs-v2.3.4
    iojs-v2.4.0
    iojs-v2.5.0
    iojs-v3.0.0
    iojs-v3.1.0
    iojs-v3.2.0
    iojs-v3.3.0
->  iojs-v3.3.1
```

As you can see when I try to install 10.15.1, I get version not found. When I run ls-remote, it's listing some pretty old stuff. Did I miss something in my setup?

Comment: The fact that it's only listing iojs stuff is certainly suspicious. What's the output from `cat ~/.nvmrc`?

Comment: "Pretty old stuff" meaning what? iojs isn't node. Are you sure your nvm install isn't hosed? What's your nvm config look like?

Comment: sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~/development/lakefrontcargo-v2-cloud-functions$ nvm --version
0.34.0

Comment: how do i check the config?

Comment: I would try reinstalling nvm from scratch. Also: 10.15.1 is the LTS version, what happens if you try `nvm install --lts`?

Comment: By looking at the file Trott indicated.

Comment: @Trott sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~/development/lakefrontcargo-v2-cloud-functions$ cat ~/.nvmrc
cat: /home/sandra/.nvmrc: No such file or directory

Comment: how did you install nvm?

Comment: What's the output of `env | grep NVM`? You might have a mirror configured via environment variables that needs to be unset or reset.

Answer (score 8):

Judging from the output, your remote is https://iojs.org/dist/ when you probably want https://nodejs.org/dist/.

Things to check:

- Check `~/.nvmrc` for a remote/mirror being set.
- Check `env | grep NVM`. If you have `NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR` or `NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR` set to an unconventional value, that may be the source of the issue.

If all else fails, update/reinstall:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash && source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~$  env | grep NVM
NVM_DIR=/home/sandra/.nvm
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
NVM_RC_VERSION=

Comment: What if you reinstall with `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash && source .bashrc` ?

Comment: Installing the latest version fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

Try providing a mirror URL:

```sh
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist nvm install v10.20.1
```